# Liferay is Unable to Process Template?

Tags: liferay

I've just upgraded from Liferay CE to EE 6.2, and have successfully deployed the WAR on my weblogic 12c appserver. However, I am getting this error while trying to access my portal:

```
An unexpected system error occurred.

Unable to process template _SERVLET_CONTEXT_/html/themes/classic/templates/portal_normal.vm
```

I've read that this might be a cache issue, and I've deleted all temporary files and restarted my server but am still getting this error.

Any ideas as to why this occurs?

Comment: Try to undeploy and redeploy the theme.

Comment: I don't have a custom theme deployed anymore, but my logs suggest it's still searching for it. Will get back to you

Comment: Hi, can you please indicate the solution ? You have marked the response, but it is not clear what solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen it before, but can't remember the exact circumstances. AFAIK it's been a temporary issue and I'm puzzled that restarting the server doesn't help..

However I've found [LPS-12683](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-12683), an issue that is marked as fixed, but maybe you find some circumstances in the description that haven't been fixed. Also [this forum entry](https://www.liferay.com/en/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/24260431) contains a nice hint to check

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the **init.ftl** file from your parent theme and fix occurrences of:

```
stringUtil.equals(x, y)
```

in

```
x == y
```